# How does $C$ small imply $Set^{C^{op}}$ locally small?

Tags: category-theory

I read in some notebook that $C$ small implies $Set^{C^{op}}$ locally small,
but I don't see what is the reasoning used, because the Yoneda lemma is not mentioned so that it is probably not needed...

Could somebody propose me a track?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When $C$ is a small category and $D$ is a locally small category, then $D^C$ is locally small. The reason is that for functors $F,G : C \to D$ the set of natural transformations $F \to G$ embeds into $\prod_{x \in \mathrm{ob}(C)} \hom(F(x),G(x))$, which is a product of sets, therefore also a set.

Comment: Now $\hom(F(x),G(x))$ is in $D$. So, this argument also uses that $D$ is locally small. E.g. let $D$ be a big monoid, and $C:=1$ the terminal category...

Comment: @Berci There are people who don't believe in categories that are not locally small...

Comment: Thank you very much Martin and Berci! Yes, I agree with Berci, this last part uses the fact that $D = Set$ so that its $hom$ are sets.

Comment: Sure. I've corrected it.

Comment: @Zhen, you are wrong. As explained on [MO](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/3278/whats-a-reasonable-category-that-is-not-locally-small), [spans](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/%28infinity%2Cn%29-category+of+spans) categories are not locally small...

Comment: @ZhenLin: I know what you mean, but now in this context of (locally) smallness, I felt this remark was needed.

Comment: @almaus I know plenty of categories that are not locally small. Some people choose not to accept this.

Comment: @Zhen Ok, sorry I think I misunderstood your point. As long as you can define these categories, and while they do not imply a contradiction in the theory, they exist, right? (assumed that, of course, in maths, existing= existing as a mathematical object)