# Existence of not locally small categories

Tags: category-theory

I had a strange remark answered to one of my questions some time ago. My question was involving "locally small categories", and that comment was saying that the existence of **not** locally small categories is doubtful. However, I can find (well-defined) examples of such categories on the net, so that it seems clear to me that they exist...
But somebody could explain me what are the origin of the doubts?

Comment: Well, the collection of all sets is certainly well-defined, yet some people say such a thing does not exist. The question is of "legitimacy" more than whether we can define it at all.

Comment: Then, we say that the collection of all sets (in fact, the category Sets) is not a set (or, "does not exist _as_ a set", that can be proved). But then, we do say that the locally small categories do not exist _as_ "what"?

Comment: In other terms, a large category is not a _what_?

Comment: can you link the question/answer that started your doubts?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/356219/how-does-c-small-imply-setcop-locally-small

(by the way, a typo in my comment above, read instead: But then, we do say that the **not** locally small categories do not exist _as_ "what"?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of authors who reserve the word ‘category’ for what others would call locally small categories, e.g. Adámek and Rosický in *Locally presentable and accessible categories*. (This becomes troublesome later when they start talking about the category of functors between two not-necessarily-small categories!) The issue is purely terminological/philosophical.

Some (other) authors also refer to possibly-class-sized models of the first-order theory of categories as ‘metacategories’, e.g. Mac Lane in *Categories for the working mathematician*. (Note that in CWM, every category has a *set* of objects and a *set* of morphisms, but that Mac Lane distinguishes between *small* sets and general sets!)

Answer (score 1):

The *smallness* notion is relative to the framework you are working in : to say that something is a set, you have to define what is a set.

Considering a model $\mathcal U$ of a set theory (say ZFC), you can then define the $\mathcal U$-locally small categories. Then you have a canonical example of such a category : the category of $\mathcal U$-small collections, that is the elements of the model $\mathcal U$, and the applications between them.

The doubts are therefore about the existence of such a model $\mathcal U$, i.e. the consistency of ZFC. (See Gödel's second incompleteness theorem.)

Comment: Thank you! That is a very interesting track.
However, a set theory permitting such not locally small categories to exist [as a category! I do not say as a set] (as with Gödel's theorem) is so closed to intuitive world that isn't it risky to say it has a consistency flaw? And, until now nobody has found any contradiction in set theory (or ZFC) so isn't easy to say it can be not consistent without showing where is the contradiction?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking and if you understood my answer properly. Gödel's second incompleteness theorem shows : if $\mathrm{ZFC} \vdash \mathrm{Con(ZFC)}$ then $\mathrm{ZFC} \vdash \neg \mathrm{Con(ZFC)}$, that is proving the consistency of ZFC _inside_ the framework of ZFC would make ZFC inconsistent (and then makes it a non suitable framework for developing mathematics). The debate is the following : if ZFC is supposed to be the world of all mathematics, then it must be consistent and then ZFC cannot prove it althoug this consistency is a part of mathematics...

Comment: Now, I don't understand what you're looking for : your original post asks about whether or not locally small categories can be defined, but all your comments focus on non locally small categories.

Comment: Ok, sorry!!! I just forgot the negation in my original post.... I corrected it now. What a shame (><')

Comment: Ok, so I think Zhen Lin has answered that. I might just add that a motivation to consider only locally small categories is the Yoneda embedding and lemma that need the $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal C}(A,B)$ to be sets.